# using ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor to repeatedly schedule tasks for AndEngine

Tags: java, android, andengine

This is my first real foray into Android programming, but I feel like I'm having more of a Java problem- some sort of major misunderstanding about how ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor works (though I'm willing to entertain the idea that it's an AndEngine problem with AnimatedSprites, too).  Essentially, I want the sprite to be motionless until an onFling occurs.  The sprite animates, and one second later, stops again.  The user has to keep Fling-ing to "swim" the sprite through the water.  The issue I'm having is with the animation.  If you have more than one Fling in a 1 second timespan, the animation only displays one or two frames before stopping, and it feels like the "stop the animation" tasks are stacking up.  I'll check and make sure the Flings are long enough and in the right direction after I get all this working.  When I first instantiate the ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor, I offer it a pool size of 1, which to my understanding, means that it can't have more than one task sitting in the queue at a time.  On top of that, before I call the .schedule(), I .remove() the task, just to make sure there's nothing in there.  I'm sure this is something simple, just some misunderstanding I have about how to use this properly.  I'll paste the relevant portions of code down here:

```
...

private ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor shed = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);
private Runnable slowDown = new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        if (eelSprite.isAnimationRunning())
            eelSprite.stopAnimation(0);
    };
};

...

public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
        float velocityY) {

    shed.remove(slowDown);
    shed.schedule(slowDown, 1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

    if (!(eelSprite.isAnimationRunning()))
        eelSprite.animate(frame_duration, 0, 12, true);

return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question touches a tricky subject.
As a first comment, I'd like to stress that when dealing with `ExecutorService`, you should probably stick to coding to interfaces and not implementations. This should avoid some of the complexity of what you are trying to do.

Case in point, you mention the use of the remove() method which is public but not present in the `(Scheduled)ExecutorService` interface. Which means using this probably entails some implementation specific behavior you may not completely control.

From the Javadoc of the remove method on `ThreadPoolExecutor`:

```
/**
 * Removes this task from the executor's internal queue if it is
 * present, thus causing it not to be run if it has not already
 * started.
 *
 * <p> This method may be useful as one part of a cancellation
 * scheme.  It may fail to remove tasks that have been converted
 * into other forms before being placed on the internal queue. For
 * example, a task entered using {@code submit} might be
 * converted into a form that maintains {@code Future} status.
 * However, in such cases, method {@link #purge} may be used to
 * remove those Futures that have been cancelled.
 *
 * @param task the task to remove
 * @return true if the task was removed
 */
```

Please note the part about the implementation maybe converting the `Runnable` you pass to another form, making it impossible for the remove() method to work when you pass it the same `Runnable` instance you used to submit work.
Furthermore, note that there is no guarantee your removal will work, it all depends on wether or not the task already started, in which case, you have to check for race conditions.
So I would advise you against using this particular method.

About your instanciation of the `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`, you may have misread the javadoc too. First, I would also stick, whenever possible to the factory methods provided by the `Executors` class to create the pool.
The javadoc for `Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(int)` states:

```
/**
 * Creates a thread pool that can schedule commands to run after a
 * given delay, or to execute periodically.
 * @param corePoolSize the number of threads to keep in the pool,
 * even if they are idle.
 * @return a newly created scheduled thread pool
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException if {@code corePoolSize < 0}
 */
```

Which mean the int argument is a "core pool size". Core being a keyword here. If you drill down to the implementation, it actually uses the same method you called in your snippet so no change here actually.
I'm saving you a bit of reading here, but the "core" pool size is the minimum number of threads that will be kept alive in the pool (once they will be started, the pool generally does not preemptively creates the threads, but that is implementation, not contract as far as I can recall). This has nothing to do with the maximum number of threads.
Actually, if you drill down still further, you'll see that the constructor you used will eventually build an unlimited pool, that can spawn as many threads as needed.

As a consequence, the jobs you submit to your pool may execute concurrently. If you want a Single threaded pool, you might want to use the `Executors.newSingleThreadedScheduledExecutor` factory method.

Finally, there is your job cancellation needs. So how does one cancel jobs that have been sumbitted ? Well, when you submit a job, `ExecutorService` instances usually give you back a `Future` object.
This `Future` object has cancellation logic embedded. It allows you to set a cancel flag on your submitted job (which will prevent it from actully running if it has not started yet), and if it has already started, can also provoque a Thread interruption.

Hope this has clarified the semantics a bit.

Comment: Wow, so much for a simple misunderstanding.  I was hoping for a "oh, you just forgot the..."  That's an excellent explanation, and I appreciate the time you put into it.  Looks like I've got some reading to do- Executors obviously don't work at all like I thought they did.